# How to load a variable from shiny to the global Environment?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

How can I do this?

I have a simple shiny app that reads a csv file and when I stoped the shiny app I can see this csv in the global environment. I used this code:

```
# Server ------------------------------------------------------------------

server = function(input, output, session){
    # Listens for click from element with ID=chck_file
    
    observeEvent(input$chck1_file,{
        # Check if file exists
        if ( file.exists( isolate({input$fname}) ) ){
            data <- reactiveValues()
            # Display text
            output$text <- renderText({ paste("File exists in: ",getwd(),sep="") })

            data <- input$fname
            print(data)
            df = read.csv(data)
            output$table1 <- renderTable(df)
            assign('data',df,envir=.GlobalEnv)
            #print(summary(data))


        }
        else{
            output$text <- renderText({ paste("No such file in: ",getwd(),sep="") })
        }
    })
    
}
```

With the function assign() I can take this csv file and load in the global environment but this happens until I close my shiny app. How can I have this dataframe in my global environment but without closing my shiny app?

Comment: You can't run any other R code while your shiny app is running. It blocks the console. Maybe you want to write it to disc so you can read it with a separate process.

Comment: I running this application in the background with jobRunScript()